# arrays of void pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stack, void-pointers

again this question is also origined from "Thinking in C++" Chapter7, Q#7. I believe the Stack header file should be changed to Stack.h

```
        #ifndef STACK_H
        #define STACK_H

        class Stack {
          struct Link {
            void* data;
            Link* next;
            Link(void* dat, Link* nxt);
            ~Link();
          }* head;
        public:
          Stack();
          Stack(void* arr[], int size);
          ~Stack();
          void push(void* dat);
          void* peek();
          void* pop();
        };
```

and the implementation of Stack::Stack(void* arr[], int size) in Stack.cpp, I believe could be like:

```
       Stack::Stack(void* arr[], int size)
       {
         for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
          {
            push(arr[i]);
          }
       }
```

However, in the main test file StackTest.cpp, how could I pass the address of a string array to this constructor? Here is what I come up with:

```
          #include "Stack.h"
          #include "require.h"
          #include <iostream>
          #include <string>
          using namespace std;

          int main() {

            string tst_arr[] = {"hi 1", "hi 2", "hi 3"};
            Stack string_arr((void**)tst_arr, 3);
            string* s;
            while((s = (string*)string_arr.pop()) != 0) {
              cout << *s << endl;
              delete s;
            }
          }
```

But it has some segmentation fault. What I could think of is to change Stack::Stack(void* arr[], int size) to Stack::Stack(string arr[], int size), however it doesn't satisfies the question requirement. The purpose of Stack to store generic objects, including string for example. I believe I still have difficulty to understand the conceipt of void* pointer and array of pointers and the chagne between string array to void* array etc... Anyone could help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: `(void **)tst_arr` is technically wrong, though it might not be the source of your problem.

Comment: Eh, I'd say abandon this insanity. You won't learn anything useful this way (`void*` shouldn't be used in C++ at all) anyway. Learn templates first and then try to write your stack (and then again, don't use it in the real code — use standard library containers instead).

Comment: "Thinking in C++" is obviously a misnomer.  This guy thinks in C.

Comment: Every time you end up with `void**` you know you are lots. Just leave it alone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Stack constructor asks for an array of pointers on stuffs, and you give it an array of objects. As a bonus, I give you proper main function and freeing memory ^^

```
#include <cstdlib>
// --- Includes your stuffs ---

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  string* tst_arr[] = new string[3];
  tst_arr[0] = new string("hi 1");
  tst_arr[1] = new string("hi 2");
  tst_arr[2] = new string("hi 3");
  Stack string_arr((void**)tst_arr, 3);

  // --- Do your stuffs ---

  for(int i =0; i < 3; ++i)
    delete tst_arr[i];
  delete[] tst_arr;

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please don't try this at home kids!  :-)  There is a std::stack just because of this.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I believe the array initialization should be changed to: string* tst_arr[3] = { new string("hi 1"), new string("hi 2"), new string("hi 3")}; otherwise, the complier will give you some error as above. for the memory free, I'm still digging into it, since Stack->pop already freed the pointer, I don't think either delete tst_arr[i] or delete[] tst_arr is necessary based on my initialization, right?

Comment: to Bo: imagine you are asked to implement a stack youself in an interview, can you say "there is std::stack existed, kid, don't you know that?" And I think it makes sense, even wheel do exist, there must be someone who know how to make them, right?

Comment: So if your pop function call *delete*, then yes, no need to delete like I did on my snippet. But in general, it's nice to separate things the jobs, here being *memory management* and *a stack*. By doing the *delete* in your *pop* method, your stack also takes the role of memory management. You might need to stack pointers without deleting them, happens quite often, like when working with trees or graphs...